# Ocaml, Module Graphics - Queuing keypresses

Tags: ocaml

I am writing a simple game in Ocaml, using its module `Graphics` to perform drawing and interaction. I came across the problem that `Graphics.read_key()` queues all presses for later use, therefore when I hold a key for a while then many "presses" are put into memory. After release the action is still performed.

Is there any way to delete entries from this queue, or just (even better) not queue them at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THis is problably not the most beautiful solution, but you can use `key_pressed`.
This function will return true if a keypress is available. 
So once you have read a keypress with `read_key` you can flush your queue by calling `read_key` until `key_pressed` is false and ignoring the result.

```
(* flush_kp : unit -> unit *)
let flush_kp () = while key_pressed () do
                      let c = read_key ()
                      in ()
                  done ;;
```

Hope this could help.